# How can I hide a block in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

There is one div inside which foreach works for me. Before this div I do a check

```
@if($events)
 <div class="card mb-5">
 ....
```

If true, then show the block, if false, do not show. But the block is still visible, it returns me an empty collection. How to fix it?

```
public function index($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $events = $user->events()->orderBy('eventdata', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `get()` method it always returns Collection of items but sometimes empty. I think you are checking whether `$events` collection is empty or not. So, you have to use `$events->count()` inside if

```php
@if($events->count())
 <div class="card mb-5">
 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@forelse($events as $event)
 <div class="card mb-5">
 ....
@empty
 Do something if there is no event
 ...
@endforelse
```

`@forelse` checks if $events variable empty or not. If it is empty then `@empty` block will be rendered else `@forelse` block will be rendered. `@forelse` is like a combination of `@foreach @if and @else` directives

Comment: Please add it to your answer, not as a comment 

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
@if(count($events)>0)
    <div class="card mb-5">
```